# Storage place of Session, cache and cookies in System

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc, session, browser-cache

I'm working on ASP.NET MVC Application. Facing few problems in session timeout. I want to know the basics like **#1. Where  Session, cache , tempdata values stored in system** and 
**#2. How it is deleted from the storage automatically/manually after certain period.**
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Session is stored in-memory by default

Comment: thanks for a quick response @VsevolodGoloviznin. I need to know the physical location in system.

Comment: It's in the memory of the running process, it doesn't have any 'physical' location.

Answer (score 0):

Sessions are stored on the server, by default these are set to 20mins or are overriden by there server/site configuration. Timeout issue - [How to set session timeout in web.config](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1205828/set-session-timeout-in-web-config)

Cache- well there is server cache and browser cache, so it depends which cache as to where it is stored.  On the client side its just a copy of the html and various other assets to make it quicker to access.  The location depends on your machine setup.

Cookies - These are stored on your machine, there is no specific place, its dependant on your machines setup, temp files, group policy etc.

Most browsers check for the latest version of content, but you can force content expiry on the server.