# Why is my session timeout happening early?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, session, session-timeout

I have set session timeout to 2880 seconds (48 minutes) in my web.config file which is:

```
<system.web>
    <authentication mode="Forms">
        <forms loginUrl="~/Account/Login" timeout="2880" />
    </authentication>
    <sessionState mode="InProc" timeout="2880" cookieless="false" customProvider="DefaultSessionProvider" >
        <providers>
            <add name="DefaultSessionProvider" type="System.Web.Providers.DefaultSessionStateProvider, System.Web.Providers, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=xxxxxxxxxxxxx" connectionStringName="DefaultConnection" />
        </providers>
    </sessionState>
</system.web>
```

When I run this program locally, it's working, but when I test it online after deploying, my session times out after 20 minutes.

Comment: How do you deploy? Does your deployment process apply any web.config transformations? If it does, have a look at the web.release.config file and make sure the timeout value there is not altered.

Comment: @iamruss no it doesn't apply any transformations and web.release.config have same timeout value.

Answer (score 0):

In `sessionState`, the time-out is given in minutes....try changing the line to:

```
<sessionState mode="InProc" timeout="48" cookieless="false" customProvider="DefaultSessionProvider" >
```

And have a look...

Comment: Is it 48 minutes? @samGhatak

Comment: 2880 sec is 48 mins....so I guessed that

Answer (score 0):

The timeout attribute in sessionState allows you to set the time in minutes,and default timeout is 20 minutes.

you can use.

```
<sessionState mode="InProc" timeout="2880" cookieless="false" />
```

for more information refer this links.
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-in/library/h6bb9cz9(v=vs.85).aspx,
[How to set session timeout in web.config](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1205828/how-to-set-session-timeout-in-web-config)