# How do you change session timeout in IIS 8.5?

Tags: iis-8

I'm in IIS 8.5 on Windows Server 2012 R2 and I want to see what the session timeout is.

Under "Feature view", I see a session category so I open that up. Session state is set to in-process. Further down the window I see options to set timeouts but they are for cookies. I looked in the application pool and I saw an idle timeout set to 20 minutes: is this the session timeout? I'm used to IIS 7 where you click on the "ASP" feature and set it in there.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Yes, that is the session timeout setting in the "Session State" section.

[image: Where to find the Session State settings]

[image: Where the timeout setting is]

You can also control it programatically in the "web.config" file. Please see [How to set session timeout in web.config](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1205828/1115360). IIS Manager will change that for you with your current method.

Comment: when you say "Yes" are your referring to the setting I found in the application pool setting, outside of the features view?

Comment: @Roto I added some pictures to hopefully make it clear. It is the "Time-out (in minutes)" setting, which has the (default) value of 20 in the picture.

Answer (score 17):

In IIS, open a list of your sites and select one.
Then select "ASP" in the site properties under the "IIS" entry

[image]

Now just change the voice about "TimeOut", the time you prefer and you're done!
[image]

Finally check your Application Pool's idle timeout that application pool idle timeout too matches your session timeout.

[image]