Session Timeout Issue with MVC Application Behind F5 Load Balancer Need Advice on Settings for Session Persistence
I have two servers running the same MVC web application behind an F5 load balancer. Despite correctly configuring session timeouts in IIS, sessions are expiring after only a few minutes of user inactivity on the website. What methods or algorithms can be adjusted in the F5 load balancer settings to maintain session persistence?
IIS side there is everything is correct.

How do you configure session timeouts in IIS? you can refer to this link on how to set session timeouts: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39153581/how-do-you-change-session-timeout-in-iis-8-5.

I have done settings in iis, under my web.config , then i idle timeout also i have set 600 minutes

What authentication method do you use? This will also affect the Session Timeout. In addition, you can also check if there is any relevant information in the Event Viewer.

In F5, Create Persistence profile and set Timeout value.

Log in to the Configuration utility.
Navigate to Local Traffic > Profiles.
Select the Persistence tab.
Select the relevant persistence profile (not a cookie type persistence profile).
Select the Custom box next to the Timeout setting.
Specify a new value in seconds for the Timeout setting.
Select Update.

Impact of procedure: Lengthy timeouts can increase the memory usage of the BIG-IP because persistence entries will stay in the persistence table longer. Increase the value to a timeout that is only long enough to allow the application to work properly.
More details you will find here
