# Session variable in ASP.NET MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I need to create something like a session variable in .net MVC.
I'm using ViewData. First I set it in my Controller Index:

```
public ActionResult Index(int id)
    {
        ViewData["myID"] = id;
    }
```

Then, I'll need to use it in another function of the same controller. However, I have to send it to my view. Store the data into a . Then read it again.
View:

```
<input type="hidden" id="myID" name="myID" value='@ViewData["myID"]'  />
```

Other function of the controller where I get the id:

```
[HttpPost, ValidateInput(false)]
    public ActionResult Test(FormCollection form)
    {
        var pId = form["myID"];
    }
```

It works, but looks wrong (I'm new in .net mvc). Is there a way where I can set this id one time in my controller and then read/get it when I need?

Thanks

Comment: ViewData!=Session

Comment: Why not just use `Session`? It works just find in MVC. Otherwise, what you're doing is just fine - use `ViewData` to send the data to the view, and a form control to send it back to the controller.

Comment: I couldn't find anything about session in MVC

Answer (score 12, accepted):

try this

for set

```
System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Session["Id"] = 1;
```

for get

```
var id=Convert.ToInt32(System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Session["Id"]);
```

Comment: Perfect. Thanks! Just a question... Does this session expire after a period of time?

Comment: yes it  expiered after period .
see this links
[How to set session timeout in web.config](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1205828/how-to-set-session-timeout-in-web-config)