# Session Time Out issue

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, web-config

I am creating a C# MVC5 Application. I have mentioned session timeout to be 60 minutes in `web.config` but it's not working and sessions break after couple of minutes.

Here is the code I added in `web.config`:

```
<system.web>
    <sessionState mode="InProc" timeout="60"></sessionState>
    <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5" maxRequestLength="25360" />
    <authentication mode="Forms">
        <forms loginUrl="~/Account/Login" timeout="2" />
    </authentication>    
    <!--<authentication mode="None" />-->
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.5" />
</system.web>
```

Comment: Do you have cookies enabled in the browser?

Comment: What does `timeout="2"` do?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Forms authentication timeout vs sessionState timeout](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17812994/forms-authentication-timeout-vs-sessionstate-timeout)

Answer (score 0):

I think your misusing the mode section in here.

```
<system.web>
    <sessionState timeout="60"></sessionState>
</system.web>
```

see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1205854/4399484) for more information.

Answer (score 0):

There are various options to make session active until the user logged out.

And timeout="60" or greater value is not a good way to do it because if you have many active users to your application, it stores user's session for 60 minutes also when user closed the application.

**Solution**

You can set timeout="10" and do a server hit (timeout value in config - 1) just to tell server your user is still here.

That callback request can be **ajax** or **iframe with a meta tag**.

**Working Sample:**

Put an iframe on your MasterPage or HeaderControl and pass URL to some page in your application and add this meta tag on that page or control

```
<meta id="MetaRefresh" 
      http-equiv="refresh" 
      content="21600;url=KeepSessionAlive.aspx" 
      runat="server" />
```

**OR Ajax Request**

```
setInterval(function () {
            if (localStorage.getItem("LastSessionHit") == '' || (((new Date - new Date(localStorage.getItem("LastSessionHit"))) / 1000 / 60) >= 9)) {
                $.ajax({ url: "KeepSessionAlive.aspx", }).done(function () {
                    $('#SessionLastHit').val(new Date);
                    localStorage.setItem("LastSessionHit", $('#SessionLastHit').val());
                    Console.log(err);
                }).error(function (err) {
                    Console.log(err);
                });
            }
        }, 60000);
```