# How to set session state in wen.config file in asp.net c#?

Tags: c#, asp.net, session, timeout

```
<system.web>      
   <sessionState mode="InProc" timeout="25" cookieless="false"></sessionState>  
</system.web>
```

This is how i set session timeout in my web.config file.But it's not working.Session goes null after redirecting the pages 3 to 4 times or if not doing anything for 3 to 5 minutes.

Comment: Is this happening locally (on your machine), or is it an issue on one/multiple web server(s)?

Comment: Locally on my machine.

Comment: I am sorry, I cannot help you significantly. In your case I would try setting `cookieless` property to `true`, because client side might not support cookies. I would also try multiple web browsers. More info that might be helpful: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.configuration.sessionstatesection.cookieless?view=netframework-4.8   ,   
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1205828/how-to-set-session-timeout-in-web-config