# asp.net C# keep the session alive as long as the user is active

Tags: c#, asp.net, session

I made a simple web app using asp.net C# and I made a code to logout automatically from the website and redirect the user to the login page when the session expire, but I have a problem which is the website logout and redirect the user to the login page even if the user is active and clicking on buttons and moving the mouse and in this case I want the session to be alive and make it expire when the user don't do anything during the timeout period just like most of the websites.

Here is my code to end session:

web.config:

```
<sessionState timeout="1"></sessionState>
```

main_page.aspx:

```
protected override void OnPreRender(EventArgs e)
{
    base.OnPreRender(e);
    AutoRedirect();
}

public void AutoRedirect()
{
    int int_MilliSecondsTimeOut = (this.Session.Timeout * 6000);
    string str_Script = @"
           <script type='text/javascript'> 
               intervalset = window.setInterval('Redirect()'," +
                   int_MilliSecondsTimeOut.ToString() + @");
               function Redirect()
               {
                   window.location.href='/login.aspx'; 
               }
           </script>";

    ClientScript.RegisterClientScriptBlock(this.GetType(), "Redirect", str_Script);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

let not talk about Application's timeout
[How to set session timeout in web.config](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1205828/how-to-set-session-timeout-in-web-config)

In your Javascript I think you need to stop setInterval
[Stop setInterval call in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/109086/stop-setinterval-call-in-javascript)

so why not use all task in aspx page 's javascript like

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
     ResetTheTimer();
     $('body').mousemove(function() { // or other events
           ResetTheTimer();
           alert('clear!');
     });
 
});
var intervalset ;
var MilliSecondsTimeOut = 12000;
function ResetTheTimer(){
    
    clearInterval(intervalset);
    intervalset = window.setInterval(Redirect,  MilliSecondsTimeOut );
             
}
  function Redirect()
  {alert(1);   
  //window.location.href='/login.aspx'; 
  }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

And then to make application alive you need some interval to postback to code behind too.

Comment: thanks  for the replay I tried your answer but it doesn't logout and finish the session

Comment: It doesn't logout and finish the session , you mean it's not go to login.aspx or it's go to the page and not terminate user's session . Could you verify that the JavaScript is working by remove  $('body').mousemove  part ?

Comment: the session stay alive and ever end even that I set MilliSecondsTimeOut = 600 and left the mouse but still the session alive but it should end if I am not moving the mouse

Comment: also there is a little mistake in the first line in the code it should be like this:   $(document).ready(function () {

Comment: Sorry,there are some mistake in my code . I updated my script please try/edit it from code snippet , the alert 1 mean the redirect is called

Comment: @jim but can you show the MilliSecondsTimeOut  value dynamically decreasing I tried display it but it show only the default first value 12000