# Invalid session id

Tags: .net, web-services

I get System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapException : Invalid session id header when my webservice is consumed by client.

Any thoughts? This happened when a user logged in more than 6 hrs in the UI & didn't do any operation.

Thanks.

Comment: Looks like sort of Session Timeout

Comment: Yes pls. tell me how to handle this timeout. Am using c# web service.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/648992/session-timeout-in-asp-net

Comment: http://forums.sforce.com/t5/NET-Development/URGENT-Error-while-making-a-Login-call-using-C/m-p/60456

Comment: @Jani- Many thanks, i want the client consuming app to show "Session expired" as a pop up, is there any way that can be shown in the client app based on session timeout.

Answer (score 1):

Based on the comment discussion I would want to add here that it appears to be related to the session timeout as mentioned.  However, the question about having the client app show something specific.  That is something that the client application will have to handle on its own.

if you have access to code the client app you can handle it, otherwise the developer of that app will have to make the modifications.