# Session of ASP.net page gets expired even I have made changes in web.config's session timeout value

Tags: c#, asp.net

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Session timeout in ASP.NET](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/648992/session-timeout-in-asp-net)

Hello Guys, 
          In my ASP.net Application, my Session get expired if a page remains open untouched for 10-15 minutes, even through my web.config file i have changed the session timeout property to 60.

Can u suggest some solution.