# session expiring soon

Tags: asp.net

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Session timeout in ASP.NET](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/648992/session-timeout-in-asp-net)

I am working is ASP.NET and using Session transfer method for page locking. In my case the session is being expired very soon than that of my requirement. Is there any way to increase session expiry time that default time?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use **[`Session.Timeout`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms525473%28v=vs.90%29.aspx)** property to set timeout limit of your choice

Comment: @Charlie - Can you please provide me with exact syntax?

Comment: Session.Timeout = 10;    //sets Session Timeout limit to 10 minutes

Comment: Is this to be in web.config file or at .cs file?

Comment: it should be in .cs file

Comment: I could not understand its syntax in .cs file.

Comment: Can you please provide me with proper syntax where to be placed for a button click and Session["transfer"] = "hello";

Answer (score 1):

web.config

```
<system.web>
    <sessionState timeout="540"/> 
</system.web>
```

That what you're after?

More information on [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/h6bb9cz9%28v=VS.100%29.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

Use this code in your web.config and set timeout to whatever you want to. The default timeout is 20 mins.

```
<configuration>
  <system.web>
     <sessionState 
         timeout="100" 
     />
  </system.web>
</configuration>
```

From your code behind you can use following

```
Session.TimeOut=100;
```