# Is Session timeout when using Windows authentication possible?

Tags: asp.net, single-sign-on

I have implemented SSO into my ASPX application and set the authentication mode as follows:

```
<authentication mode="Windows" />
```

Is it possible to enforce a session timeout for applications which use the authentication mode from above?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [windows authentication session timeout](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6923191/windows-authentication-session-timeout)

Comment: @prd - I didn't find answer for - "Is it possible to enforce a session timeout for applications which use the authentication mode from above?" there