# Timed out on web page

Tags: asp.net, iis-6

So we have been stuck on a connection timeout issue and we are lost.

All pages on this asp.net web application times out after exactly 2 minutes.
Saying:
connection timed out
description: connection timed out

All articles on the internet suggest it is the asp.net web config setting "executionTimeout". (Here is ours)

```
<httpRuntime executionTimeout="3600" requestValidationMode="2.0" maxRequestLength="15360" />
```

But obviously ours is set to way above 2 mins. A colleague of mine also fiddle with the iis settings without success.

Any suggestions?

EDIT: This does not happen on debug at all, which makes me lean towards it being an IIS issue.

EDIT: We don't believe it to be an asp.net session issue since we are still logged in and can browse to other secure pages after this happens

Resolved: So after some more investigation we discovered that the timeout issue was just from when accessing the website from within our intranet. Apparently we have some daemon software (Websense) running on the network that was the root of all this evil.

Comment: I think the 2 minute timeout may be enforced by the client, not the server. What are you using to access your pages, a browser?

Comment: All pages? What about static content?

Comment: Refer this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/648992/session-timeout-in-asp-net

Comment: @Zruty Yes both IE... and firefox, and they display the EXACT same error message which leads me to believe it is on the server.

Comment: @Andrew Barber all pages that take more than 2 min to return from the server

Comment: I'm asking if static content times out; like images or CSS/JS files.

Comment: @Andrew, I think the pages in question DO render for a long period of time, but they shouldn't time out after 2 minutes nevertheless

Answer (score 1):

The above you mentioned should work, Look for the following in your web.config file (maybe its a issue of session timeout):

```
<system.web>
    <authentication mode="Forms">
          <forms timeout="20"/>
    </authentication>

    <sessionState timeout="20"  />
</system.web>
```

Increase the timeout time you are using.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Ours is 60mins on both timeouts, but thanks for the suggestion