# Asp.net MVC 3 session not expiring on expected time

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3

Session in asp.net is not expiring on expected time. Below is my part of web.config file for session configuration. Here i want to expire my session in 2 minutes and redirect the user to login page for test purpose. Here session expires about 6 to 7 minutes later.

```
<system.web>
    <sessionState mode="InProc" timeout="2" />
    <authentication mode="Forms">
          <forms loginUrl="/Home/Login" timeout="2" />
    </authentication>
</system.web>
```

Thanks.

Comment: Possibly same as http://stackoverflow.com/questions/648992/session-timeout-in-asp-net/650126#650126

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Make sure you have disabled sliding expiration:

```
<system.web>
    <sessionState mode="InProc" timeout="2" />
    <authentication mode="Forms">
          <forms loginUrl="/Home/Login" timeout="2" slidingExpiration="false" />
    </authentication>
</system.web>
```

Now no matter whether you are sending requests to the application during the period, the forms authentication cookie won't be renewed.