# my site logs out to quick because of executionTimeout

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-config, session-timeout

someone made a site in .net which am taking over.

when someone is logged in, it logs you out automatically after a short while.

in the web.config theres this code which am assuming controls the time:

```
     <httpRuntime
       executionTimeout="12000"
       maxRequestLength="307200"
       useFullyQualifiedRedirectUrl="false"
       minFreeThreads="8"
       minLocalRequestFreeThreads="4"
       appRequestQueueLimit="100"
       enableVersionHeader="true"
       requestValidationMode="2.0"
    />
```

now what does the "12000" number mean

can i change the length of time in this code

and whats the diffrence between executionTimeout and maxRequestLength

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're using Authentication Forms, look for system.web - authentication in web.config. There, you have a Timeout parameter.

```
<authentication mode="Forms">
    <forms loginUrl="login.aspx" name=".ASPNETAUTH" protection="None" path="/" timeout="60"/>
</authentication>
```

Comment: Nothing about Authentication. Configures ASP.NET HTTP run-time settings that determine how to process a request for an ASP.NET application.

Comment: @al123 Have you solved? If so, could you mark an answer?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that is the property you are looking for what is more likely is that the session is timing out

[Session timeout in ASP.NET](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/648992/session-timeout-in-asp-net)

Should help you

Comment: its already timeout. but i need to make the timeout longer! i think its it might be executionTimeout, but not sure