# restrict access to a .net page without a valid session vb.net

Tags: mysql, vb.net, session

I currently have a login page login.aspx that copies "affID" into a session and uses it on another page dashboard.aspx

login.aspx file looks like this :

```
Dim Query As String
            Query = "select * from mdxmain.taffiliate where affID = '" & username.Text & "' and affPassword = '" & password.Text & "'"
            COMMAND = New MySqlCommand(Query, MysqlConn)
            Session("affID") = username.Text


            READER = COMMAND.ExecuteReader

            Dim count As Integer
            count = 0

            While READER.Read
                count = count + 1
            End While

            If count = 1 Then


                Response.Redirect("dashboard.aspx")

            Else
                Literal1.Text = "Invalid credentials"
            End If

            MysqlConn.Close()

        Finally

        End Try
        MysqlConn.Dispose()
```

dashboard.aspx session load file looks like this :

```
Dim userid As String = HttpContext.Current.Session("affID")
```

I need help with not allowing access to the dashboard.aspx file without having a valid session. Also how to timeout the session after 2minutes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your dashboard page_load event, check if the session variable is `nothing`, if it is, then redirect to your login page.

```
Protected Sub Page_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Me.Load

    Dim userid As String = HttpContext.Current.Session("affID") 
    if ( userid is Nothing) then
        Response.Redirect("login.aspx")
    end if

End Sub
```

**Update**
For the timeout there is some good information [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/648992/session-timeout-in-asp-net)

Comment: Thank you and how do i set a timeout on this session for example of 1 minute