# IIS Session Reset

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, session, iis-8.5

I'm working on a web project that contains sessions.
I have a few pages on the web app:
Logon.aspx - If the verification of user is OK, a new session is created:

Pseudo:

```
    If User.connected = True Then
        Session("isLogin") = True
        Response.Redirect("Content.aspx")
    End If
```

In the “Content.aspx” in the Page_Init event:

```
    If Session("isLogin") = False Then
        Response.Redirect("Logon.aspx")
    End If
```

Web.config settings:

```
<forms loginUrl="~/Logon.aspx" timeout="50" />
<sessionState mode="InProc" timeout="60">
```

When I run it **locally (IIS Express), all works as expected**.
 However, when I run it on the IIS server, after a few minutes the session resets and throws me to Logon.aspx.

**IIS Server information:**

I am using IIS 8.5

Idle Time-out (minutes): 60

Regular Time Interval (minutes): 1740

How can I fix this session reset?

P.S.
I have read all your suggestions (until Mar 14 '15). 
Also, read all suggestions at [session-timeout-in-asp-net](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/648992/session-timeout-in-asp-net)), but could not find a solution.

Comment: Don't use in-process session unless for testing purposes. IIS worker process can be shut down or recycled, which simply drops all sessions. If you don't plan to learn IIS, you should.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Session timeout in ASP.NET](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/648992/session-timeout-in-asp-net)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have previously used Application Pool with the settings: **.NET v4.5**

When I change Application Pool’s settings to **.NET v4.5 Classic**, the problem stopped!