# Session Expiration Issue in Asp.Net Application

Tags: c#, asp.net, session

I am facing session expiring issue in my ASP.NET Web Forms application. The session is timing out randomly. After 5 to 10 minutes(not exact time but happening randomly) there is no any explicit session. Timeout declaration elsewhere in the code. Given below are settings I have defined in Web.Config file. Any help is much appreciated

```
<sessionState mode="InProc" cookieless="UseCookies" timeout="30" />
<httpRuntime executionTimeout="1200" maxRequestLength="6144" />
```

Comment: possibly duplicate - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/648992/session-timeout-in-asp-net

Comment: are u run Web Forms application. in local iis?

Comment: all session is not work i think

Comment: That is expected behavior for in-memory session state - whenever app pool restarted for whatever reason you loose state.