# Session timeout web.config

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, iis, web-config, session-timeout

I've set the timeout of my application to `540` as follows:

```
<system.web>
    <authentication mode="None" />
    <sessionState timeout="540" />
    <customErrors mode="Off" />
    <compilation targetFramework="4.5" debug="true" />
    <pages controlRenderingCompatibilityVersion="4.0" />
</system.web>
```

The IIS timeout is set to 20 (I can't touch this part as it's on a shared-server).

Everytime I run the application it disconnected after 20 minutes, I assume it's due to the IIS timeout.

How can I override the IIS timeout to fit my web.config timeout?
on my computer (where I have control on the IIS timeout), it's working good, but not on the server.

Thank you all.

Comment: also show your `IdentityConfig` file

Comment: How are you defining that your session is `timeout`? Are you sure you are using `authentication` as `none`? Also check this.. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/648992/session-timeout-in-asp-net

Comment: Thank you for the reply, how can i be sure that i'm using none? the session is timeout when ideal time is reached. i've used the form authentication but it didn't work for me. about the IdentityConfig  the data inside it doesn't refer to timeout.