# Decreasing ASP.NET session timeout in web.config does not work

Tags: asp.net, web-config, session-timeout

I'm using visual studio 2015 and want to decrease default session timeout to some value like 1 or 2, but unfortunately it does not work! I tried to do that in two ways: 1. by editing web.config file; and 2. by using Session_Start event in Global.asax. I searched web and found some problems in increasing session timeout, but I want to decrease it. So where is the problem?

my web.config session timeout setting code is:

```
<configuration>
    ...
    <system.web>
        ...
        <sessionState mode="InProc" timeout="1" customProvider="DefaultSessionProvider">
            <providers>
                <add name="DefaultSessionProvider" type="System.Web.Providers.DefaultSessionStateProvider, System.Web.Providers, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" connectionStringName="DefaultConnection"/>
            </providers>
        </sessionState>
        ...
    </system.web>
    ...
</configuration>
```

Comment: Are you using form authentication ?
Refer this link. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/648992/session-timeout-in-asp-net

Comment: No i don't. also this problem occurs on increasing session timeout, i want to decrease!