# Viewstate expires after some time for application page in SharePoint 2013?

Tags: asp.net, sharepoint-2013, viewstate, applicationpage

I have a simple ASP application page added in  a SharePoint project just for presentation purposes, so it's ASP web forms page is hosted in SharePoint.

HTML:

```
</asp:Content>
<asp:Content ID="Main" ContentPlaceHolderID="PlaceHolderMain" runat="server">
    <asp:Label runat="server">Number 1:</asp:Label>
    <asp:TextBox ID="num1" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
    <asp:Label runat="server">Number 2:</asp:Label>
    <asp:TextBox ID="num2" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
    <asp:Label runat="server">Result:</asp:Label>
    <asp:TextBox ID="res" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
    <asp:Button Text="ADD Numbers" runat="server" OnClick="Unnamed_Click" />
    <asp:ListBox runat="server" ID="list" />
    <asp:Label runat="server" ID="previousListValue"></asp:Label>
    <asp:Label runat="server">Exception:</asp:Label>
    <asp:TextBox ID="exception" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
</asp:Content>
```

Here is code behind:

```
public partial class Default : LayoutsPageBase
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!Page.IsPostBack)
        {
            list.DataSource = new List<ListItem>() { 
                new ListItem("value1", "1"),
                new ListItem("value2", "2"),
                new ListItem("value3", "3"),
            };
            list.DataBind();
        }
    }

    protected void Unnamed_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            res.Text = Convert.ToString(int.Parse(num1.Text) + int.Parse(num2.Text));
            previousListValue.Text = "Previous list selected value is: " + list.SelectedItem.Value;
            exception.Text = string.Empty;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {

            exception.Text = ex.GetType().ToString() + "\t" + ex.Message;
        }
    }
}
```

When you click "ADD Numbers" button and addition of `num1` and `num2` textboxes is appended to the `res` textbox and selected value of `ListBox` is shown in label next to it. This works flawlessly if correct values are entered for a number and an item is selected in `ListBox`.

If the page is left (not interacted with) for about 10-15 minutes and "ADD Numbers" button is clicked, `NullReferenceException` will be thrown for `list.SelectedItem.Value` and also textBoxes will be empty. What happened is that the application is in postBack state(`Page.IsPostBack` is true) but viewstate is not restored.

I guess this has something to do with ViewState being moved to distributed cache as of [version 2013](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/besidethepoint/2013/03/27/appfabric-caching-and-sharepoint-concepts-and-examples-part-1/) but can someone clarify this for me, and suggest me the most effective way to go about this, without changing AppFabric configuration, because 10-15 minutes of ViewState perversion is not acceptable.

Answer (score 0):

As the ViewState is saved in the user's session, it is possible for
ViewState to expire if a page is not posted back within the session
expiration time.

You can configure your session timeout in web.config file ([Session timeout in ASP.NET](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/648992/session-timeout-in-asp-net)):

```
<sessionState timeout="60"  />
```

(Where 50 and 60 are minutes)

You can also check if your session expired using this sample code in Master Page's Page_Load method:

```
if (Session.Contents.Count == 0)
{
    //Session dead!
}
else
{
    //Session alive!
}
```

Or save the logged user and test if it's null:

```
if (Session["userId"] == null)
{
    //Session dead!
}
else
{
    //Session alive!
}
```