# Session Expires after 15-20 Minutes in asp.net core 2.0. Any solution Not working

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-core-2.0, session-state, session-timeout

Hello Buddies I hope you all good. I am having session expiration problem. it took weeks but not solved
yet I hope I will get help from here.

```
services.Configure<CookiePolicyOptions>(options =>
            {
            });
            services.AddDistributedMemoryCache();
            services.AddSession(
                options =>
                {
                    options.IdleTimeout = TimeSpan.FromDays(1);
                });
            services.AddMemoryCache();
            services.AddMvc().AddJsonOptions(options => options.SerializerSettings.ContractResolver = new Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.DefaultContractResolver());
           
            services.AddTransient<IUserStore<ApplicationUser>, UserStore>();
            services.AddTransient<IRoleStore<IdentityRole>, RoleStore>();

            services.AddIdentity<ApplicationUser, IdentityRole>()
                .AddDefaultTokenProviders();
            services.Configure<IISOptions>(options =>
            {
                options.ForwardClientCertificate = true;
            });
            services.ConfigureApplicationCookie(o =>
            {
                o.Cookie.Name = ".ERP_Cockie";
                o.ExpireTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromHours(24);
                o.SlidingExpiration = true;
            });
```

I have Tried this this is my startup File
apart from this
I have changes the idleTimeout from IIS also. not working in my case.
this is the Image of settings in my iis.
[the Settings inside the IIS](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hDNdK.jpg)

But Not coming to the point of solution.

Can Anyone of you provide an example code or proper settings that may be missing from my side
I have produced a big application. moving from session to other way is not possible for me.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Session timeout in ASP.NET](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/648992/session-timeout-in-asp-net)

Comment: No it has'nt helped me.

Comment: Does this issue only happen on IIS server but work well on local?

Comment: No Same on Both sides. on localhost it is doing same

Comment: Can Someone Please Provide the solution I am still suffering from this issue