# Session.Timeout is being ignored

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, session

I have an ASP.NET MVC application with the following in place:

Upon successful login:

```
Session.Timeout = 9999;
```

and in the `web.config` file, I have:

```
<sessionState timeout="9999" />
```

Additionally: authentication mode is not specified, as it links to Azure AD for authentication.

Now the problem: if I leave the application for a period of time after logging in (approx 1.5 hours), if I try to access a session variable, it will return null (eg upon page refresh).

Somewhere, the session is timing out much sooner than the specified time in both the code and `web.config` file. Is there anywhere else I need to check?

Comment: possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/648992/session-timeout-in-asp-net

Comment: What's the version? MVC 4, MVC 5, MVC 6?

Comment: @SNBS MVC version 4

Comment: Possible cause https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/561199/the-session-state-is-timeout-in-seconds-instead-of (issue is in the ASP.NET platform, so no matter that it's about Web Forms)

Comment: As an experiment, try setting `cookieless="true"` in `sessionState` in `web.config` and tell me if that works. *You should not do that in a production environment, for it embeds session data into the URL and thus poses a big security risk.*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You also have to configure your idle timeout, since the logic of session timing out, can be reset if a user is not idle.

For MSDN reference [IdleTimeOut & SessionOptions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.builder.sessionoptions?view=aspnetcore-7.0)

[image: IdleTimeOut]

---

Make sure you setup/configure your `IdleTimeout` in your `SessionOptions`
Like so:

```
// Appsettings.json setup your idle options
"SessionOptions": {
    "IdleTimeout": "00:10:00"
}
```

[image: SessionOptions]

Answer (score 1):

The session timeout configuration work as you've described, authentication token issued by Azure AD have their own lifetime that could affect your session. Azure AD tokens have their own expiration time, which might differ from the session timeout you've set in your application.

Make sure to check the token lifetime settings in your Azure AD configuration.

***Configure session timeout***

1. In the Power Platform admin center, select an environment.
2. Select `Settings > Product > Privacy + Security`.
3. Set `Session Expiration` and `Inactivity timeout`. These settings apply to all users.

ref: [Link1](https://nishantrana.me/2022/04/18/security-enhancements-24-hours-maximum-user-session-timeout-removed-in-dynamics-365-crm/), [link2](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-platform/admin/user-session-management#configure-session-timeout)